# Dropwizard equivalent of Spring's @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, asynchronous, dropwizard

Is there a way of creating threads managed by a Threadpool in Dropwizard in the same way it can be done in Spring Boot with `@Async` and `@Schedule` annotations?

A Threadpool can be created programatically, but I'd like to know if Dropwizard has a simple solution for this like Spring Boot.

Comment: Do you mean the behaviour described here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/?

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank, yes

Comment: I am not aware of anything provided by Dropwizard that is comparable. It may be out of scope for Dropwizard.

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous processing can be done in Dropwizard using Java 8 features. You can use **CompletableFuture** to achieve this. Here is an API example of Asynchronous processing in Dropwizard:

```
@Timed
@GET
@Path("/async")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response async() {
    Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<>();
    CompletableFuture<Void> future = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(15 * 1000);
            logger.info("Processing complete");
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            logger.error("Error in PingResource.async(): {}", ie.getMessage());
        }
    });
    response.put("message", "Request is under process");
    return Response.ok(response).build();
}
```

I have explained Asynchronous processing in Dropwizard in my blog post. In the blog post, please refer to the headings **Step 3** and **API calls and results**): http://softwaredevelopercentral.blogspot.com/2017/07/dropwizard-tutorial.html